# Summing up products of powers of matrices with known coefficients

Tags: matrices

I'm playing a game where I am handed some series in powers of some-handed-to-me matrix $A$.
Then I must calculate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n A^n$, where I get to choose the coefficients after seeing the matrix $A$. I must choose positive coefficients, and the series must not diverge. So far, for each $A$ I am handed, assuming $A$ is not the zero matrix, I choose $c_n = \frac{1}{\lvert\lvert 2A \lvert\vert^n}$. Then we have that the sum is just $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Big(\frac{A}{\lvert\lvert 2A \lvert\vert}\Big)^n = (I-\frac{A}{\lvert\lvert 2A \lvert\vert})^{-1}$. Then the infinite sum becomes an inversion problem for a finite dimensional, invertible matrix, which can be solved in a finite number of steps. If I can solve the series in a finite number of steps, I win, and I have been able to win in this manner for every $A$ my adversary has given me.

---

In order to make the game more challenging, my adversary will now hand me two matrices $A$ and $B$. I must now sum the following series:$\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (A^{\dagger})^n B A^n$. I can still choose the positive coefficients $c_n$ in the series, and I must choose the coefficients so that I can write the value of this sum in a finite number of steps, such as by writing it as a matrix inverse as I did above.

What coefficients can I choose generally so that I can win the modified game?

Comment: We can apply the same basic strategy one we note that [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) lets us identify the map $B \mapsto A^\dagger B A$ with $A^\top \otimes A^\dagger$ ($\otimes$ denotes a Kronecker product).  In other words, it suffices to consider series of the form $\sum_n c_n [A^\top \otimes A^\dagger]^n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Please write those two sentences as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've rewritten my comment as an answer, as you recommended. For many people, the information that I gave might not be enough of a solution; however, I'm glad to see that this was enough for you to fill in the blanks (or at least to get the sense that you could).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply the same basic strategy once we note that [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) lets us identify the map $B \mapsto A^\dagger B A$ with $A^\top \otimes A^\dagger$ ($\otimes$ denotes a Kronecker product). In other words, it suffices to consider series of the form $\sum_n c_n[A^\top \otimes A^\dagger]^n$.